# no stack trace for jasmine-node errors

Tags: node.js, stack-trace, jasmine

I'm using node.js and the jasmine-node npm module to run tests.  This works perfectly except if the code produces an error.  I get no stacktrace.  For example, one of my tests only outputs this:

`Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

No stack trace.  This makes finding these errors so time-consuming that I'm looking for alternatives to jasmine-node.

How can I get jasmine-node to output the full stack trace with the error?  The --verbose command-line flag doesn't do it.

Comment: It would probably be useful if you could post an example piece of the test code that is breaking along with a copy of the implementation.

Comment: The problem is that there's so much code I don't know what snippet to post, because there's no stack trace.

Comment: If your code is TDD style, there should be a healthy number of tests for any significant body of code. Given that, you can comment out a test at a time until you flush out the problematic code/test

Answer (score 7):

You can use jasmine-node's `--captureExceptions` option to output the stack trace of global exceptions.

Comment: I have found that this does not work. I usually use Tape, and Jasmine is a mess in comparison. Even Node's built in asserts do a better job on the whole.

Comment: this one help me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

Whilst I haven't used the jasmine-node npm, i have come across this kind of error before. In my experience, those sorts of errors get reported when an async loop outside the scope of your test/impl fails...

What we've done to catch all exceptions of that kind is add this code prior to execution

```
process.on('uncaughtException',function(e) {
    sys.log("Caught unhandled exception: " + e);
    sys.log(" ---> : " + e.stack);
});
```